# Sortable bar chart in d3 v4

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to take Mike Bostock's Sortable Bar Chart code and convert it to a horizontal bar chart. https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885705

My bar chart appears just fine but the console gives this error message whenever the input is clicked:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.change (test3.html:168)
>       at pt.each (d3.v4.min.js:2)
>       at test3.html:161

I have a feeling this is related to my using v4 of d3 rather than v3 but I'm not really sure.

Here's the whole script:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("#graphlocation").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        ;

    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
          .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scaleBand()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
        .ticks(10);

    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

    d3.tsv("15.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
      if (error) throw error;

      x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

      y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.datesort; }))
        .paddingInner(0.1)
        .paddingOuter(0.5);


      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis)
        .append("text")
          .attr("class", "label")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
          .attr("y", -5)
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("Frequency");

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis);

      svg.selectAll(".bar")
          .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("x", 0)
          .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.datesort); })
          .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); });

    });

    function type(d) {
      d.frequency = +d.frequency;
      return d;
    }
d3.select("input").on("change", change);

 var sortTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
   d3.select("input").property("checked", true).each(change);
}, 2000);

  function change() {
    clearTimeout(sortTimeout);

    // Copy-on-write since tweens are evaluated after a delay.
    var y0 = y.domain(data.sort(this.checked
        ? function(a, b) { return b.datesort - a.datesort; }
        : function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.value, b.value); })
        .map(function(d) { return d.value; }))
        .copy();

    svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .sort(function(a, b) { return y0(a.value) - y0(b.value); });

    var transition = svg.transition().duration(750),
        delay = function(d, i) { return i * 50; };

    transition.selectAll(".bar")
        .delay(delay)
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y0(d.value); });

    transition.select(".y.axis")
        .call(yAxis)
      .selectAll("g")
        .delay(delay);
  }
```

Line 168 is `var y0 = y.domain(data.sort(this.checked`and line 161 is `d3.select("input").property("checked", true).each(change);`

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Move all your function `change` to inside the callback of d3.tsv, and `d3.select("input").on("change", change);` as well.